# Object storage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, list, object, database-design

I am working on a database design where job-seekers must list their previous work experience.

Work experience is a class that has:

- The employer
- The position held

I would like to model the classes and show the link between a jobseeker and their previous work experience.

I was thinking of creating a table for previous work experience and referencing it to a job-seeker, but each job-seeker can have multiple entries for work experience and this could get messy.

Another way to do it would be to store all the work experience of the users as a list in the jobseeker table.

I'm not sure which to go with and would like some advice on which is acceptable and which is not. Any other alternatives are welcome and in fact requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like this set-up.

**This will hold all the users past experience**

```
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `position_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `position_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`position_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**This will hold the users personal data**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**This will hold users work experience** - a "middle" table for `positions` and `users`.

```
CREATE TABLE `work_experience` (
  `seeker_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seeker_position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seeker_employer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `seeker_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`seeker_id`),
  KEY `positon_id` (`seeker_position`),
  KEY `user_id` (`seeker_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`seeker_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `positon_id` FOREIGN KEY (`seeker_position`) REFERENCES `positions` (`position_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It would then function like;

```
SELECT users.* FROM users;
+---------+----------------+---------------+
| user_id | user_firstname | user_lastname |
+---------+----------------+---------------+
|       1 | bob            | bob           |
+---------+----------------+---------------+
1 row in set

SELECT positions.* FROM positions;
+-------------+-------------------+
| position_id | position_name     |
+-------------+-------------------+
|           1 | stackoverflow guy |
+-------------+-------------------+
1 row in set

SELECT work_experience.* FROM work_experience;
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| seeker_id | seeker_position | seeker_employer | seeker_user |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|         1 |               1 | StackExchange   |           1 |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
1 row in set
```

User "1" (bob) has had work experience at "StackExchange" being a "stackoverflow guy"

[image]

- `work_experience.seeker_user` references `users.user_id`
- `work_experience.seeker_position` references `positions.position_id`

Comment: I like this design. Do you think it is a appropriate for a even though the positions will be specified by the users of the system themselves? these are not fixed. Also I'd like to know, if a user adds another position, how do we now add that to his experience.

Comment: Yes. The reason for the positions table is so that you don't store the same data twice. For example "System administration" and "Sys admin" are the same; yet they'd take up 2 entries. I would allow users to specify positions, but give them a list of current stored positions that are similar to the position they try and enter.

Comment: I see. But say that we know that every job-seeker has a unique would we now just get rid of the positions table and put position as a field in the work_experience table, essentially ending up with the structure suggested by @peter-m?

Comment: You can, **but** your tables won't be normalised, as you'd have "System administration" and "Sys admin", or even multiple entries for "Sys admin".

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea is the common way to handle this "many-to-one" situation.

Use one table for storing the jobseekers, another one to store the previous work experience, with each PWE having a foreign key to the jobseeker. (e.g. a "jobseekerId" field.)

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm also thinking is there a way to have the entire work history of a jobseeker in one record? So that all the previous positions are represented in this record. Or is this one-to-many representation the best way to do it?

Comment: Well, you could somehow serialize (e.g. JSON) all this information into one varchar field in the jobseeker table... But in essence, database tables are lists of information. So anything that is a list (especially a list of variable length) would fit best in its own table. So you can solve your problem both ways, but using two tables better fits the structure that databases provide for you.